# Part-time training: using free time at work for personal projects?

Tags: training, time-off, part-time

I'm a project manager's assistant in a small software development enterprise, in **part-time training**. My tutor is nice but always underestimating by capabilities. I'm not going to stay in this enterprise after my studies are done, so I'm not complaining about it since I won't get a raise, being a part-time trainee.

Last example in date, I have some job to do for which he gave me two weeks; I'm almost done and it took me four days, all while playing a lot of flash game on internet (I'm such a dedicated worker).

**Is it ok to use the leftover time to work on my personal projects** (mostly meaning studying new frameworks and stuff), or should I talk my boss about giving me more work? Knowing that he already has a good image of me as an employee, thus he won't give me a bad end-training grade.

Sorry for my lacking english skills.

Edit: As explained, there is a slight difference between my case and the one mine is considered a duplicate of: I'm in part-time training, and even though my company is nice and all, I have absolutely no feelings for it, and I won't stay there. It may not make a big difference in answers, though, since [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/7039/26687) seems to fit.

Comment: Hi Kilazur, is there any difference between your question and the duplicate question? If so, [edit] and flag for reopening - it looks like they are exactly the same question. Thanks!

Comment: They're slightly different in context: this person is a full-time employee, I'm a part-time trainee. But I guess the output is the same.